# How to store successors with efficient access?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Lets say I have the following ordered values {2,4,6,9,15}. Given one of these numbers, I have to find its successor. For fast access I used to do it like this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

const vector<uint_fast64_t> v={0,0,4,0,6,0,9,0,0,15};

cout<<v[2]<<endl; //4
cout<<v[4]<<endl; //6
cout<<v[6]<<endl; //9
cout<<v[9]<<endl; //15

return 0;
```

}

What can I do if I have a few thousand values like 1840791, 51840799, 51840823, 51840831 and 51840855. My sparse vector approach is not practical any more.

So, I tried to used a binary search.

```
 successor=v[distance(v.begin(),lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),value))+1]
```

But that's too slow, because I do this operation millions of times.

Are there any other techniques to store and efficiently access the element-successor relationship?

Comment: A `std::set` is an option, although it also has logarithmic complexity, like `lower_bound()`. You'll have to come up with a custom container, of some-kind, hand-tailored to your application's particulars.